Unity Engine Networking doesn't count as "programming or software development problem"?

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: Unity Mirror can't connect to WAN, LAN and port-forwarding works fine
I asked it on Stack Overflow, but it got closed because "This question is not about programming or software development. It is not currently accepting answers."
I thought problems with Unity Engine Networking (Mirror Framework) counts as programming, doesn't it?
I know that there is text about it "General computing, networking (unrelated to specific programming problems), optimization of working code, and general-purpose tools (the list is not exhaustive) do not" but my question is not about routers wifi and etc. It is about why Mirror framework doesn't want to work with WAN.


Your question doesn't really show that you are writing any code. It reads a lot like "I press a button on some UI, but the tool is not connecting". If it is really a question about your code, then you probably should show the code. Please also check the tag description of mirror tag.

That looks like a network configuration question to me and offtopic for the same reason. Some reasons why it might not be working for you: you might have configured port forwarding only for TCP but your server is UDP, your firewall might be blocking UDP, etc. you might have noticed both these suggestions are about network / configuration rather than about programming.

As a note, all questions about Unity (including programming ones) are on-topic on our sister site, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, so you can always ask such a question there (though of course, the audience is a bit smaller).

"Unity Engine Networking doesn't count as "programming or software development problem"?" - if it doesn't involve a programming problem, no. I'm sorry that you are having trouble using the Unity tooling. I see Unity.com has a community section with multiple options including Discord... seems like the perfect place to ask for assistance.

@Gimby There's no need to push the user to another medium altogether, my comment directly above yours highlights a Stack Exchange site dedicated to this kind of question already.
